# How can I get my mac to hide/reveal files with git local branching?

Tags: git

I'm curious as to how the author of this git tutorial: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-git-branches

is able to have git hide/reveal files in the local system using branching. In my mac when I try to do this, it is still visible in the file system. no matter what branch I'm currently on. At first I thought this was only possible in the remote server of git, but realized they had to push the changes. How can I accomplish this in my mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see the confusion here. Git uses `commits` to mark checkpoints of your work in time. While you're working with your app which is version-controlled by git, you may as well be adding or removing files. These changes get *staged for commit*, which means you can create a `commit` out of them. The branches, are basically commits, tagged by a user-friendly name. So let's say I have the following flow:

I'm on my `master` branch and start off a new branch from `master`

```
$ git checkout master -b my-test-branch
```

I've now switched to a new branch, which is the same with `master` at that specific point in time.

I can now create a file and delete a file:

```
$ touch mytest.rb # create the file
$ rm anotherfile.rb # remove a random file
$ git status # show the status of the repo
Changes not staged for commit:
  deleted:  anotherfile.rb
Untracked files:
  mytest.rb
```

Now, if I do `git add --all`, and `git commit -m "My test commit"`, the branch 
my `my-test-branch` will no longer be the same as master but will have a file added and a file deleted.

If I switch back to the `master` branch by running `git checkout master`, you'll see that the file `mytest.rb` doesn't exist and `anotherfile.rb` which was deleted in branch `my-test-branch` is in place.

Hope this clears things up, if not there's an [amazing interactive git tutorial](https://try.github.io/levels/1/challenges/1) provided by the nice people at GitHub

Comment: Where is your shell session locally or on github's server? The issue I'm having with the tutorial is that they are using the ls command. Is the ls command also suppose to reflect the git status of files? If so does this affect the gui when viewing the folder?

Comment: This applies to both local and remote sessions. The best-practice here is to work locally, then use the remote server only to pull & serve the application, so the remote server should have a read-only access.

Comment: The `ls` command is a command that applies to both linux & mac (all *nix flavoured systems as they're called) which lists the files in a directory. It's not part of `git` so it's not supposed to reflect the git status of the files. `git status` is the command appropriate for that. There's also `git ls` which can list remote files as well but let's keep it out of the equation for now.

Comment: That's what I mean, I find the linked tutorial confusing because the ls command in the tutorial is also affecting the file system output.  So to be clear when the author does the ls in the tutorial, the files should always output as is in the directory and not the way the tutorial represents it (I assume the author is working locally)

Comment: The author uses `ls` to indicate the files are in place. I guess the alternative would be posting a screenshot of their file manager. The author is probably working locally from what I can see (they're doing a `git push` at the end). I suggest you try more tutorials since you find that confusing :). I've posted GitHub's interactive tutorial on my answer